# Is there a way to do Like against a list of Values?

Tags: soql

Is there a way to mix LIKE operator with IN ?
Something Like

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE IN:nameList
```

Where nameList is list of String?
Is this is possible ?
(I can make a dynamic query by doing OR with all the elements, but was looking for a more elegant way to do this)

Comment: You can't do a LIKE with IN. You have to use the OR query. Or maybe you can use SOSL.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

No, but you can query like this which does the same thing as what you're trying to do:

```
String[] filters = new String[]{'acme%','ib%'};
List<Accounts> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :filters];
```

Comment: That's a neat solution to the problem.

Comment: ahhh really neat. Somehow thought IN can only operator on collections

Comment: Yea this method is a huge time saver. Also, with using the OR option, you run into the query length limitation eventually.

Comment: NIce solution, +1!

Comment: fantastic solution!! my upvote for this...I thought there would be no option to do a like for multiple strings. Fortunately i found this. Thanks drakored!!

Comment: Is this documented or did you just find this out by trial and error?

Comment: Trial and error, although it might be documented, not sure.

Comment: man, it's a shame it's not clearly documented, this is a pretty sweet syntax to hide