# In SOQL, how do I get just the left N charactes for a compare?

Tags: soql

In SQL, I could to something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, PostalCode FROM Account WHERE LEFT( PostalCode, 5 ) IN ('84117','84070'...)
```

How do I do something similar in SOQL? I see date functions and aggregate functions in the SOQL documentation but nothing on others.

I've tried the following but the query errors:

```
select Id, name from zip_code__c where name.left(5)  = '84070'
```

If someone can help with this, it sure would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about something like `WHERE PostalCode like '84117%'`?

Comment: Or use a Formula Field / External Id Text Field populated by Workflow Field update for the comparison.

Comment: Mike, the problem is that I have to compare the left 5 characters of a zip code against a set. The wild card does not work with Name in ('84070%', '84117%' ).

Comment: techtrekker, That would probably work but the field count is a premium here and I'd prefer to not have to burn a field for this.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/is-there-a-way-to-do-like-against-a-list-of-values

Comment: @DougB - you should've posted that as an answer!

Comment: Just think of the sweet sweet karma I have missed out on! :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doug B's response has the answer. I'll show a simple snippet so you don't have to follow the link if you don't want to.

```
String[] filter = new String[]{'84117%', '84070%'};
Zip_Code__c[] zipList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Zip_Code__c WHERE Name LIKE :filter];
```

Comment: Glad that helped, it's a neat trick to know.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Use the `%` wildcard

   ```
   Select Id, Name From zip_code__c Where Name like '84070%'
   ```
2. Create a formula field

   Name_First_Five__c Formula Field:

   ```
   LEFT(Name, 5)
   ```

   Query:

   ```
   Select Id, Name From zip_code__c Where Name_First_Five__c = '84070'
   ```