# Is there a way to do Like against a list of Values using the PHP API?

Tags: soql, php

I need a way to find all articles that are related to a list of tags.

Assuming the Articles_*c object has a column Tags*_c that holds a comma separated list of all tags that are applied to the article. Something like this:

```
$articleTags == "php, newb, salesforce, soql"
```

Here is some semi-pseudo code that represents what I am trying to do:

```
$filter = array('%php%', '%soql%')
$query = "SELECT Id FROM Articles__c WHERE Tags__c LIKE $filter";
$result = $salesForceConnection->query($query);
```

Is this possible with the PHP API? If so, how do I need to format $filter for it to create a valid query to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I found a [similar post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/is-there-a-way-to-do-like-against-a-list-of-values) that appears to be the functionality I need, I just need to find a way to do the same thing with the PHP API.

Comment: You could iterate through the elements in your array and build the WHERE clause dynamically - `WHERE Tags__c LIKE $filter[i]` [when i == 0], and for the rest append - `OR Tags__c LIKE $filter[i] ` [when i > 0]

Comment: That will work alright. I wonder if there is a way to filter with a single statement like the user in the post linked above did.