# How to use LIKE and IN together in SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a requirement, for each Accountwhose name contains ‘Sale’, ‘Opportunity’, or ‘Catalog’, set Price_Type__c to ‘Net’.

This is what I code in Anonymous Apex:

```
set<string> myString = new Set<String>{'%Sale%', '%Opportunity%', '%Catalog%'};
List<Pricebook2> myList = [select Name from Pricebook2 where name LIKE IN: myString];
for (Pricebook2 rec : myList) {
    rec.Is_Auto_Maintained__c  = true;
    rec.Price_Type__c ='Net;'
}
update myList;
```

and it threw an error : "

> expecting a colon, found 'IN'

". So is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 26):

Somehow I found the solution :

```
String[] nameFilters = new String[]{'%Sale%', '%Opportunity%', '%Catalog%'};
List<Pricebook2> myList =
    [select Name
     from Pricebook2
     where name LIKE :nameFilters 
    ];
for (Pricebook2 rec : myList) {
        rec.Is_Auto_Maintained__c  = true;
        rec.Price_Type__c ='Net';
}
update myList;
```

Comment: Is this working fine in your requirement?

Comment: @highfive : Yes, it is working. I checked the SObject data.

Comment: Wow....the more you know.... I never knew you could do this.  Great to know.  Found this other answer on here that confirms as well.  Learn something new everyday.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/is-there-a-way-to-do-like-against-a-list-of-values

Comment: You incorrectly added the IN operator in the original.  IN isn't needed when passing the set/list to the LIKE operator.

Comment: brilliant answer!

Answer (score 4):

You could solve this just by using some Or's.

```
string s1 = '%Sale%';
string s2 = '%Opportunity%';
string s3 = '%Catalog%';
List<Pricebook2> myList =
    [select Name
     from Pricebook2
     where Name LIKE : s1 Or Name Like : s2 Or Name Like : s3];
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only way that I'm also can think of. But if your string set is large this will be a pain

Comment: This will work, but looks like you figured it out on your own, thanks for sharing...