# SOQL: Bulk Fuzzy Searching

Tags: soql, sosl

I have a list of accounts that I would like to perform a LIKE query on. Ideally, my query would be something like:

```
SELECT id, owner.name FROM Account WHERE name LIKE IN :entityList
```

Is there any way I can do this?

The issue is that my entity names come from a third party source, which means that small variations in name may be present, i.e

> "Bay Ridge apt." VS "Bay Ridge Apartments"

It's hard to predict where the difference in spelling might be, and I was hoping that the LIKE filter might be some magical filter that can figure this out for me and match on a substring (i.e. "Bay Ridge").

The Salesforce guide doesn't include this option in their guide, so it might not be possible to combine a LIKE and an IN. Maybe there's a solution around it?

Maybe there's a way to perform a SOSL query on a list? Something like :

> Find {entityList} In Account

I can't seem to find this any where...

Any guidance?

EDIT: It seems that it's not really possible to 'bulkify' SOSL queries. I could have ran a loop, but this would have hit governor limits. Using the LIKE filter with strategic wildcards was key.

Comment: To Get Fuzzy like you want, I think you would need to do some `Natrual Language Processing`. I don't think the SF platform is really capable of what you want without investing pretty heavily. You can combine `LIKE` and `IN`, though. It's just that `LIKE` isn't nearly as magical as you want it to be.

Comment: I tried combining LIKE and IN, got a parse error (maybe was something else?). Either way, maybe a SOSL query would work? I mean, I can type these names into the salesforce search and get results - but not in SOQL with LIKE.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/is-there-a-way-to-do-like-against-a-list-of-values

Comment: Right, thats SOQL. How to perform a similar search with SOSL (mind you, it isn't just a FIND WHERE IN, the list has to be in the FIND clause)

Comment: Hmm, I am not as familiar with SOSL. If you are tied to that I am not sure how to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Nope, not tied. But it seems to be able to handle fuzzier text searches than my 'not-so-magical' LIKE  ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21026/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-zar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/is-there-a-way-to-do-like-against-a-list-of-values), you can perform `LIKE` on a list of matches. You might want to split on spaces and create a pool of candidates. It may be worthwhile to consume an extra query to try to find exact matches first. You will also probably get a better candidate pool if you use pair-wise neighbor combinations instead of individual split results.

```
public static List<Account> findCandidates(String potentialName)
{
    if (String.isBlank(potentialName)) return null;
    List<Account> candidates = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :potentialName];
    if (!candidates.isEmpty()) return candidates;

    List<String> partialMatches = new List<String>();
    for (String fragment : potentialName.split(' '))
    {
        partialMatches.add('%' + fragment + '%');
    }
    return [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :partialMatches];
}
```

To get pairwise neighbors would look something like:

```
static List<String> getFragments(String potentialName)
{
    if (String.isBlank(potentialName)) return null;

    List<String> fragments = new List<String>();
    List<String> chunks = potentialName.split(' ');

    while (chunks.size() >= 2) // starting with one word should yield an empty result
    {
        String fragment = '';
        if (!fragments.isEmpty()) fragment += '%'; //No leading wildcard
        fragment += chunks.remove(0);
        fragment += chunks.get(0);
        if (chunks.size() > 1) fragment += '%'; // No trailing wildcard
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }

    return fragments;
}
```

Comment: I still seem to be having difficulty using both LIKE and IN - I get a parsing error

Comment: You don't use the `IN` keyword, just use `List<String>` instead of `String`.

Comment: I presume the two lines between the if statements in the while loop are supposed to read `fragment += ...` not `fragments += ...` ? I am a novice and I want to make sure that List doesn't interact with operators in a special way.