# SOQL multiple LIKE matches

Tags: visualforce, soql

I am trying to figure out the best way to do multiple `LIKE` matches in a complicated soql statement.

I want to change the `hubFilter` value from just `"BCS%"` to `"BCS%,Benefit Advisor,Mgr of Ben,BSR"`.

I tried this and got nothing back so I assume it's not reading those as separate values. Any ideas?

Here is a basic example of what my query looks like:

```
list<BCS__c>hubs = new list<BCS__c>();
private string hubfilter;
if(showAll == TRUE){
    hubFilter = '%';
}else{
    hubFilter = 'BCS%';
}
hubs = [
    SELECT /*fields and subqueries*/ FROM BCS__c
    WHERE /*other clauses*/ AND Title__c LIKE :hubFilter
];
```

Comment: It looks like this question has already been answered here: [Is there a way to do Like against a list of Values?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/is-there-a-way-to-do-like-against-a-list-of-values)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a collection with `LIKE`:

```
Set<String> fuzzyMatches = new Set<String> { 'A%', 'B%', 'etc%' };
List<MyObject__c> records = [SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE Field__c LIKE :fuzzyMatches];
```

You can also define the collection inline:

```
SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE Field__c LIKE ('A%', 'B%', 'etc%')
```

---

Your specific `hubfilter` would be:

```
new Set<String> { 'BCS%', 'Benefit Advisor', 'Mgr of Ben', 'BSR' };
```

Note that you only use a fuzzy match on the first string. It is unclear if any of the other values should also be a fuzzy match.

Comment: i tried using it as `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE name LIKE ('A%', 'B%', 'etc%')` gave me error **Unknown error parsing query**

Comment: Me too. That's the solution I'm looking for to avoid a massively large query, but my excitement was a little premature

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this post in future, I ended up with this code.

```
set<string> hubfilter = new set<string>();

        if(showAll == TRUE){
            hubfilter = new Set<String> { '%' };
        }else{
            hubFilter = new Set<String> { 'BCS%', 'Benefit Advisor', 'Mgr of Ben', 'BSR' };
        }
```